# How to do nice GET URLs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

If I have a form:

```
<form method="get" action="<?=action( "SomethingController@DoSomething" ) )?>">
    <select name="SomethingID">
        <?php foreach( $somethings as $something ) : ?>
            <option value="<?=$something->id?>"><?=$something->title?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

How do I do a route for this so that my DoSomething function gets an id given to it rather than generating an ugly as hell URL like `www.example.com/project/3/something?SomethingID=7`

```
Route::get( "project/3/something/{SomethingID}", "SomethingController@DoSomething", function( $somethingID ) {
    return App::make( "SomethingController" )->DoSomething( $somethingID );
} );
```

I want the URL to be `www.example.com/project/3/something/7`

The problem is it can't be a post... because then people can never just simply go to that URL... they'd always have to post to it.

Do I need to make the dropdown box change the anchor href of a button with javascript that then generates the correct url from that?

Can't seem to find anything in here:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing

Comment: Oh... Of course :( Did I miss it? Can you link me to the relevant page please! I was within the docs for the past couple of months, haven't had to do such a thing before.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're doing everything right... I am a little confused on what you're trying to do though, and subsequently doing "wrong" (since everything seems right), so apologies in advance for the shot in the dark. Instead of the select, can you use simple a tags?

```
@foreach($somethings AS $something)
<a href="{{ URL::to('3/something/'.$something->id) }} ">{{ $something->title }}</a>
@endforeach
```

That way, clicking the link takes them to www.example.com/project/3/something/7 -> or whatever ID is generated by the link. As for routing, you could do:

```
Route::get("project/3/something/{SomethingID}", "SomethingController@getSomething");
Route::post("project/3/something/{SomethingID}", "SomethingController@postSomething");
```

And your controller:

```
public function getSomething($somethingID){
// Handle returning the view and whatever else you need
}

public function postSomething($somethingID){
// Handle the post function (i.e. do stuff.)
}
```

Those are a couple things to try when routing dependent on variable ID's, but if there's something else you're trying to accomplish, leave a comment and I'll look into that as well.

Cheers!